# Why doesn't my Angular combineLatest operate the first time you make a change on a page?

Tags: angular

I have the following combineLatest:

```
  validateAttendanceDateAndDuplicates$ = combineLatest([this.controls.attendanceDate.valueChanges, this.controls.type.valueChanges, this.$spService.clientAttendance$, this.$spService.clientProfile$]).pipe(
    tap(([attendanceDate, type, attendances, client]) => {

      console.log("in valid type top")

    const typeValueChanges$ =
      this.controls.type.valueChanges.pipe(
        mergeMap(() => {

          console.log("in valid type")

          return this.$spService.clientAttendance$;
        }),
        tap((attendances) => {
          this.validateTypeAndDate(client, attendances);
        }
      ))

      console.log("in valid attend top")

    const attendanceDateValueChanges$ =
      this.controls.attendanceDate.valueChanges.pipe(
        mergeMap(() => {

          console.log("in valid attend")

          return this.$spService.clientProfile$;
        }),
        tap(client => {
          this.validateTypeAndDate(client, attendances);
        }
      ))
      merge(typeValueChanges$, attendanceDateValueChanges$).subscribe();
    }))
```

The top pipe operation is for a type dropdown and the second is for a date picker. Here is the pattern: the first time you open a new tab in Chrome, when you pick a type, based on the console.log statements, I can see that neither the tap nor the mergeMap is entered. When you then pick a date, I can see that tap is entered, but not the mergeMap. After that, if you pick either a type or date, all works as expected. Also, the pattern is the same if you first pick a date in a new tab.

Comment: combineLatest will not emit an initial value until each observable emits at least one value. Are you sure all your observables are emitting at least once?

Comment: The type and date observables wouldn't have emitted anything before a user first clicks on them, right? Is there an alternative to combineLatest?

Comment: I'm not sure what you actually trying to do. You are waiting for this.controls.attendanceDate.valueChanges, but never use it in your tap. Same for type. Are you sure you need this combineLatest? (also be aware that in the latest version of RxJs, combineLatest is deprectated and replace by combineLatestWith)

Comment: Ah, I see your point. I just need to know when those two controls are changed, so I can then do my validations. So perhaps I don't need combineLatest. What should I use?